# Is it possible to create SSLBinding without navigating to IIS:\SSLBindings

Tags: ssl, powershell

Am trying to create SSLBinding using powershell. I have certificate in a certificate store and i proceed as below

```
 $certificate = Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -match $CertificateName } | Select-Object -First 1

cd IIS:\SslBindings

 Get-Item $certificate | New-Item 0.0.0.0!$Port
```

is it possible to create ssl binding without navigating to IIS:\SslBindings ?

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try, in your context :

```
PS C:\>  new-item -path "IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!9004"  -Value $certificate

IP Address       Port Store            Sites
----------       ---- -----            -----
0.0.0.0          9004 My


PS C:\> dir IIS:\SslBindings

IP Address       Port Store            Sites
----------       ---- -----            -----
0.0.0.0          8172 MY
0.0.0.0          9000 My
0.0.0.0          9001 My
0.0.0.0          9002 My
0.0.0.0          9003 My
0.0.0.0          9004 My
```

Now I've been hable to test.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this, when i execute it asks for the type i am not sure what the type is so i had left it there !. what should be the value for type ?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong (and a bit tired) So I edit my answer, it seems to work now.